# wrting byte array in java

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to realize a Java server / c client and I have a problem with my put method in java. 
The server receive for example the array buffer. I printed in server what it received and it was = {-17 -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 0   16  74  70  73  70  0   1   1   0   0   1   0}. 
but when I write it with

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
out.write(buffer);
```

And then I read the same file with

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
is.read(buffer);
```

I don't get the same byte array. in this Example I get : buffer = {-17  -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 -17 -65 -67 0   16  74  70  73  1   0   0   -1  -2  0   59  67}

**EDIT :**

```
private void put(String request, InputStream entreeSocket, OutputStream sortieSocket) {
    //request = "a/b/c/file.txt";
    System.out.println(request);
    String[] s = request.split(" ");
    Path path =  Paths.get(s[0]);
    String filename ="";
    int i = s[0].indexOf('/');
    //System.out.println(request+i);
    if (i != -1){//System.out.println(request.substring(i));
        filename = s[0].substring(s[0].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        s[0] = s[0].substring(0,s[0].lastIndexOf('/'));
        path = Paths.get(s[0]);
        filename = path + "/"+filename;
        if (Files.notExists(path)){
        if (!new File(s[0]).mkdirs()) return;
        }
        //System.out.println(path + " " + filename);
    }
    else filename = s[0];

    i = request.indexOf("Content-Length");
    //System.out.println(request.substring(i));
    i = request.indexOf(":",i);
    //System.out.println(request.substring(i));
    int j = request.indexOf("\r\n",i);
    int length = Integer.valueOf(request.substring(i+1,j).trim()); 
    //System.out.print(length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    j = request.indexOf("\r\n\r\n");
    request = request.substring(j+4);
    System.out.print(length);
    //length = length - request.length();
    try {
        buffer = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
        print(buffer,buffer.length);
        length -= request.getBytes("UTF-8").length;
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        out.write(buffer, 0, request.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
        length = 0;
        while(length > 0){
            int nb;
            if(length > buffer.length)
                nb = entreeSocket.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            else
                nb = entreeSocket.read(buffer,0,length);
            print(buffer,nb);
            out.write(buffer,0,nb);
            if(nb == -1) break;
            length -=nb;

        }

        sortieSocket.write(new String("205 OK\r\n").getBytes());
        out.close();



        entreeSocket.close();
        sortieSocket.close();


        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
        int nb = is.read(buffer);
        print(buffer,nb);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

That the debut of my corrupt files:

```
ef bf bd 50-4e 47 0d 0a-1a 0a 00 00-00 0d 49 48
```

That the debut of the original files

```
89 50 4e 47-0d 0a 1a 0a-00 00 00 0d-49 48 44 52
```

Comment: And...? More info is needed

Comment: `InputStream.read(byte[])` does not ensure that the number of bytes read is the same than the length of the buffer. Maybe you need to perform several calls. Check the return value of `read` which tells you the actual number of bytes read. Also, don't forget to `flush` the output stream.

Comment: It may be a good idea to sniff the communications to check the actual data being transmitted to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Are you specifying encodings on either read or write?

Comment: No, I have this problem only with binary files so the suspected the encoding problem but I have no idea how to resolve it

Comment: can you post more code for reading and writting and how you initialize buffer.

Comment: Can you add more code? I hope you flush the output stream and close it, before you begin reading from the file.

Comment: Check the number of bytes, `out.close()` being called, `int byteCountActuallyRead = is.read(buffer)` and the files size.

Comment: I can't post it now but yes I close the outputstream

Comment: Since you use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream you are working at byte level and no encoding is involved. Encoding would matter only with character streams like FileReader and FileWriter.

Comment: So what's the problem?